# Custom model binder for QueryString string parameters in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, parsing, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, model-binding

I'd like to implement some/any custom behavior for some data type, for example `DateTime` or `int`.

I've created a custom `JsonConverter` which encompasses data received from the body of a request (unless it was specified as non-json), which allows me to do just that.

But if data is passed in the query string of a request, for example `?param1=helloWorld&param2=123"`, they are handled differently and are not covered by my custom `JsonConverter`.

I've read about creating/implementing my own Custom Model Binder, but those from the looks of it are for complex types, so I'm a bit lost on how exactly I can modify an incoming query string parameter, or if that's not possible - gain access to the whole query string, searching for the parameters I want to modify, and modifying those. (decoupled from `Action` methods, similar to filters and whatnot.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> creating/implementing my own Custom Model Binder, but those from the looks of it are for complex types, so I'm a bit lost on how exactly I can modify an incoming query string parameter

You can create and apply custom model binder to simple types parameter(s), like below.

```
public IActionResult Test(string param1, [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(Param2ModelBinder))]int param2)
{
```

> decoupled from Action methods, similar to filters and whatnot.

If you do not want to directly apply custom model binder to action parameter, you can implement a custom model binder provider and specify the parameter your binder operates on, then add it to MVC's collection of providers.

*Param2ModelBinder class*

```
public class Param2ModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        // ...
        // implement it based on your actual requirement
        // code logic here
        // ...

        var model = 0;

        if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("param2").FirstOrDefault() != null)
        {
            model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<int>(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("param2").FirstOrDefault());

            // just for testing purpose
            // if received data > 100
            // set it to 100

            if ((int)model > 100)
            {
                model = 100;
            }
        }


        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

*MyCustomBinderProvider class*

```
public class MyCustomBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        // specify the parameter your binder operates on
        if (context.Metadata.ParameterName == "param2")
        {
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(Param2ModelBinder));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

*Add custom model binder provider*

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(opt=> {
    opt.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new MyCustomBinderProvider());
});
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Can the custom model binder be invoked based on the type instead of the parameter name?  This way parameter naming is not restricted to "param2" and can be anything since the custom binder looks for the type.