# Custom Json Converter For Nullable Value Type Does Not Get Called

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I have two custom converters for Uuid value type. One for nullable and other for not nullable:

```
public class NullableUuidJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Uuid?>
{
    public override bool HandleNull => true;

    public override Uuid? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (Uuid.TryParse(reader.GetString(), out var parsedUuid))
        {
            return parsedUuid;
        }
        
        return null;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Uuid? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue((string)null);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public class UuidJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Uuid>
{
    public override Uuid Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return new Uuid(reader.GetString());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Uuid value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

And they registered like this:

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Insert(0, new UuidJsonConverter());
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Insert(1, new NullableUuidJsonConverter());
                });
```

When I try to call API method which request model contains nullable Uuids:

```
[PublicAPI]
public class Request : IRequest<Response>
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "ids")] public Uuid[] CheckupIds { get; set; }
    [FromQuery(Name = "unitId")][CanBeNull] public Uuid? UnitId { get; set; }
    [FromQuery(Name = "ratingPeriodId")][CanBeNull] public Uuid? RatingPeriodId { get; set; }
}
```

UnitId and RatingPeriodId are filled with null. However if I make them simple not nullable Uuid they will be filled with actual passed values.

Comment: And `Uuid` is ?

Comment: Uuid is value type, like Guid. It is some kind of internal type in our company.

Comment: json.net doesn't have an overridable property called `HandleNull`, so it's clearly `System.Text.Json`

Comment: Your properties are all marked [`[FromQuery]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute) so they are part of the query string not the body, so **they're not JSON** and they are not going to be bound using a JSON converter.  If you need a custom binder for query string values see [Custom model binder for QueryString string parameters in ASP.NET Core 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62277271/3744182).

Comment: The discussion thread for [Custom JsonConverter never gets called by the MVC model binder/controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69887079/3744182) may also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you replies. I managed to fix this issue by using publicly available nuget Dodo.Primitives.Uuid